# Elasticsearch : Default template does not detect date

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a default template in place which looks like

```
PUT /_template/abtemp
{
    "template": "abt*",
  "settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval": "5s",
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "index.codec": "best_compression"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "message_field": {
            "match": "message",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "analyzed",
              "omit_norms": true,
              "fielddata": {
                "format": "disabled"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "analyzed",
              "omit_norms": true,
              "fielddata": {
                "format": "disabled"
              },
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

the idea here is this

1. apply the template for all indices whose name matches `abt*`
2. Only analyze a string field if it is named `message`. All other string fields will be `not_analyzed` and will have a corresponding `.raw` field

now i try to index some data into this as

```
curl -s -XPOST hostName:port/indexName/_bulk --data-binary @myFile.json
```

and here is the file

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "abtclm3","_type" : "test"} }
{   "FIELD1":1,   "FIELD2":"2015-11-18 15:32:18"",   "FIELD3":"MATTHEWS",   "FIELD4":"GARY",   "FIELD5":"",   "FIELD6":"STARMX",   "FIELD7":"AL",   "FIELD8":"05/15/2010 11:30",   "FIELD9":"05/19/2010 7:00",   "FIELD10":"05/19/2010 23:00",   "FIELD11":3275,   "FIELD12":"LC",   "FIELD13":"WIN",   "FIELD14":"05/15/2010 11:30",   "FIELD15":"LC",   "FIELD16":"POTUS",   "FIELD17":"WH",   "FIELD18":"S GROUNDS",   "FIELD19":"OFFICE",   "FIELD20":"VISITORS",   "FIELD21":"STATE ARRIVAL - MEXICO**",   "FIELD22":"08/27/2010 07:00:00 AM +0000",   "FIELD23":"MATTHEWS",   "FIELD24":"GARY",   "FIELD25":"",   "FIELD26":"STARMX",   "FIELD27":"AL",   "FIELD28":"05/15/2010 11:30",   "FIELD29":"05/19/2010 7:00",   "FIELD30":"05/19/2010 23:00",   "FIELD31":3275,   "FIELD32":"LC",   "FIELD33":"WIN",   "FIELD34":"05/15/2010 11:30",   "FIELD35":"LC",   "FIELD36":"POTUS",   "FIELD37":"WH",   "FIELD38":"S GROUNDS",   "FIELD39":"OFFICE",   "FIELD40":"VISITORS",   "FIELD41":"STATE ARRIVAL - MEXICO**",   "FIELD42":"08/27/2010 07:00:00 AM +0000" }
```

note that there are a few fields, such as `FIELD2` that should be classified as a `date`. Also, `FIELD31` should be classified as `long`. So the indexing happens and when i look at the data i see that the numbers have been correctly classified but everything else has been put under `string`. How do i make sure that the fields that have timestamps get classified as `date`s?

Comment: Provided your `myFile.csv` file is [properly formatted for bulk calls](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html), you simply need to specify `--data-binary @myFile.csv` (i.e. you missed the `@` sign)

Comment: The file needs to be json to be able to be bulk imported. And it needs to have a certain format. See here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: thanks! that worked. also, i have rephrased the questions. can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of date formats there. You need a template like this one:

```
{
  "template": "abt*",
  "settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval": "5s",
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "index.codec": "best_compression"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_date_formats":["dateOptionalTime||yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa ZZ"],
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "message_field": {
            "match": "message",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "analyzed",
              "omit_norms": true,
              "fielddata": {
                "format": "disabled"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "dates": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "date",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dateOptionalTime||yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm||mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa ZZ"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "analyzed",
              "omit_norms": true,
              "fielddata": {
                "format": "disabled"
              },
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This probably doesn't cover all the formats you have in there, you need to add the remaining ones. The idea is to specify them under `dynamic_date_formats` separated by `||` and then to specify them, also, under the `format` field for the `date` field itself.

To get an idea on what you need to do to define them, please see [this section of the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats) for builtin formats and [this piece of documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) for any custom formats you'd plan on using.